# Change li on anchor hover

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links that when I hover over, i want the entire li to change background color. It's a common effect but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

```
#topbar ul li{
            display:inline;
            margin:0 10px;
        }
        #topbar ul li a{
            color:white;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #topbar ul li a:hover{
            background-color:#323232;
        }

<div id="topbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Gallery</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="" class="nav-quote-button">Get Quote</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

At the moment, only the anchor tag changes background color but I want the entire li area to do so.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you add your html?

Comment: Post updated, html added :)

Comment: If the link is still inside the li then hovering over the link should also trigger `li:hover`.

Comment: what is the problem [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emigort/Eenfq/#&togetherjs=xfmEq2jF3e) ??

Comment: @Digzol Yes, but that won't change the styles of the `<li>`

Comment: Thanks guys, the answer below nailed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
#topbar ul li:hover {
    background-color:#323232;
}
```

Also, you need to change `li` to `display:inline-block;` instead of `display:inline;`

```
#topbar ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px;
}
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ZA4nJ/

Comment: Sorted, I had to change the li margin to padding top and bottom to get the effect but combined with what you answered, it works a treat. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
#topbar ul li:hover {
    background-color: <Insert the color here>
}
```

It's either these two lines I wrote above, or a javascript event you can use as well. It's not very needed when you have CSS, but it's another way to do this, using a library called jQuery. You may read about it, if you are interested.